# Cannot use 'sourceCpp' from a file

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to play with the [Rcpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Eddelbuettel) package from the R statistical software. Unfortunately, I cannot compile a basic example with the *sourceCpp* function. My toy example is the following:

```c
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int hello(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Saved into the file "helloworldR.cpp.

Then when I call *sourceCpp*:

```c
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("helloworldR.cpp")
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/userD/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:65:0,
                  from /home/master/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                  from helloworldR.cpp:1:
 /home/userD/map:1:1: error: stray ‘\177’ in program
  ^?ELF^B^A^A         ^B > ^A    ^K@     @       Xw          @ 8   @   ^] ^F   ^E
  ^
 /home/userD/map:1:8: warning: null character(s) ignored

make: *** [helloworldR.o] Error 1
g++  -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/master/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/userD" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c helloworldR.cpp -o helloworldR.o
 /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe for target 'helloworldR.o' failed
 Error in sourceCpp("helloworldR.cpp") :
   Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

But if I put the code as a string it works:

```
sourceCpp(code = "#include <Rcpp.h>
 + using namespace Rcpp;
 +
 + // [[Rcpp::export]]
 + int hello(int a)
 + {
 +   return a;
 + }
 + ")
 > hello(2)
 [1] 2
```

What do you think it can be? Here is my session information:

```
sessionInfo()
 R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
 Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

 Matrix products: default
 BLAS: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
 LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

 locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=ca_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
  [3] LC_TIME=ca_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ca_ES.UTF-8
  [5] LC_MONETARY=ca_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=ca_ES.UTF-8
  [7] LC_PAPER=ca_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=ca_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

 other attached packages:
 [1] ggplot2_2.2.1 Rcpp_0.12.15

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     compiler_3.4.3   lazyeval_0.2.1
  [5] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.3      pillar_1.1.0     gtable_0.2.0
  [9] tibble_1.4.2     grid_3.4.3       rlang_0.1.6      munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Please tell us, what *is* "Rcpp"?

Comment: It was wrongly spelled, it is an R package to combine C++ and R code

Comment: @JesperJuhl Click on the tag and see the info--it is an R extension package which greatly facilitates C++ integration into R.

Comment: Also a stray error and Rcpp (but probably unrelated): *[Rcpp Compiler error in r tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566312/)*

Comment: "[`ELF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)" is a hint the compiler is chewing on binary data for some reason (\177 is not in the source code, though [in other cases it may be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530960/g-error-stray-177-in-program)). It is often the result of some build system/make shenanigans.

Comment: Here is another example with ELF and \177: *[Why do I get weird stray errors with file 'cxxopts.hpp' and Meson + Ninja build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73410284/)*

Comment: Here is another example where the compiler is chewing on binary data (with an explanation of exactly how in the answer): *[Daemon on embedded Linux device using BusyBox be written in C or as a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759855/)*

Comment: Indeed, the very first byte of an ELF file is 0x7F (octal 177, decimal 127).

Answer (score 0):

You may be editing your source with an inappropriate application leaving odd things behind:

```
/home/userD/map:1:1: error: stray ‘\177’ in program
```

Take care of that first, and things will improve.

You can also *greatly* help yourself if you use one of (at least two) generators for *working* examples:

1. Call `Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackagenamehere")`
2. Use RStudio and do File -> New Project -> New Directory after which you can select Package / Package with Rcpp.

Build the generated example. Rejoice that it works.  Then modify it.

Comment: Using Rcpp.package skeleton I am able to compile and call C++ functions in R, so it works, thank you.